# python opens text file with a space between every character

Tags: python, csv, text-files

Whenever I try to open a .csv file with the python command
`fread = open('input.csv', 'r')`
it always opens the file with spaces between every single character.  I'm guessing it's something wrong with the text file because I can open other text files with the same command and they are loaded correctly.  Does anyone know why a text file would load like this in python?

Thanks.

**Update**

Ok, I got it with the help of Jarret Hardie's post

this is the code that I used to convert the file to ascii

```
fread = open('input.csv', 'rb').read()
mytext = fread.decode('utf-16')
mytext = mytext.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
fwrite = open('input-ascii.csv', 'wb')
fwrite.write(mytext)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The post by recursive is probably right... the contents of the file are likely encoded with a multi-byte charset. If this is, in fact, the case you can likely read the file in python itself without having to convert it first outside of python.

Try something like:

```
fread = open('input.csv', 'rb').read()
mytext = fread.decode('utf-16')
```

The 'b' flag ensures the file is read as binary data. You'll need to know (or guess) the original encoding... in this example, I've used utf-16, but YMMV. This will convert the file to unicode. If you truly have a file with multi-byte chars, I don't recommend converting it to ascii as you may end up losing a lot of the characters in the process.

EDIT: Thanks for uploading the file. There are two bytes at the front of the file which indicates that it does, indeed, use a wide charset. If you're curious, open the file in a hex editor as some have suggested... you'll see something in the text version like 'I.D.|.' (etc). The dot is the extra byte for each char.

The code snippet above seems to work on my machine with that file.

Answer (score 7):

The file is encoded in some unicode encoding, but you are reading it as ascii.  Try to convert the file to ascii before using it in python.

Comment: yeah, I think it's in unicode, is there a way to open the file in python, convert the file to ascii, write the file, then reopen it to load it as a csv?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't csv a simple txt file with values separated with comma.
Just try to open it with a text editor to see if the file is correctly formed.

Comment: well, it is a text file and properly formated with | characters instead of commas, but the problem is actually before I ever try to read it into the csv reader.

Answer (score 1):

To read an encoded file, you can simply replace `open` with `codecs.open`.

```
fread = codecs.open('input.csv', 'r', 'utf-16')
```

Answer (score 0):

It did never ocurred to me, but as truppo said, it must be something wrong with the file.

Try to open the file in Excel/BrOffice Calc and Save As the file as Csv again.

If the problem persists, try a subset of the data: fist 10/last 10/intermediate 10 lines of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it with the help of Jarret Hardie's post

this is the code that I used to convert the file to ascii

```
fread = open('input.csv', 'rb').read()
mytext = fread.decode('utf-16')
mytext = mytext.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
fwrite = open('input-ascii.csv', 'wb')
fwrite.write(mytext)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary mode, 'rb'.  Check it in a HEX Editor and check for null padding '00'.  Open the file in something like Scintilla Text Editor to check the characters present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick and easy way, esp if python won't parse the input correctly

```
sed 's/ \(.\)/\1/g'
```