# Difficulty reading data from a text file and converting to a float

Tags: python, string, readline

**UPDATE:**
My problem was due to the input file having an odd encoding.  Changing my opening statement to "open(os.path.join(root, 'Report.TXT'), 'r', **encoding='utf-16'**)" fixed my problem

**ORIGINAL TEXT**
I'm trying to make a program that will allow me to more easily organize data from some lab equipment.  This program recursively moves through folders, locates a file named `Report.TXT`, grabs a few numbers from it, and correctly organizes them in an excel file.  There's a lot of irrelevant information from this file, so I need to grab only a specific part of it (e.g. line 56, characters 72-95).

Here's an example of a part of one of these Report.TXT files containing information I want to grab (under the ng/uL column):

```
RetTime  Type     Area     Amt/Area    Amount   Grp   Name
 [min]         [nRIU*s]               [ng/ul]  
-------|------|----------|----------|----------|--|------------------
  4.232 BB     6164.18262 1.13680e-5 7.00746e-1    Compound1                                        
  5.046 BV     2.73487e5  1.34197e-5   36.70109    Compound2                                           
  5.391 VB     3.10324e5  1.34678e-5   41.79371    Compound3                                            
  6.145            -          -          -         Compound4                                           
  7.258            -          -          -         Compound5                                          
  8.159            -          -          -         Compound6                                           
 11.092 BB     3447.12158 2.94609e-5    1.01555    Compound7                                           
Totals :                               80.21110
```

This is only a portion of the Report.TXT, the actual "Compound1" is on line 54 of the real file.

I've managed to form something that will grab these and insert it into an excel file as a string:

```
for rootdir in range(1,tdirs+1):
    flask = 0
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(str(rootdir)):
        if 'Report.TXT' in files:
            flask += 1
            with open(os.path.join(root, 'Report.TXT'), 'r') as fin:
                print(root)
                for x in range(0,67):
                    line = fin.readline()
                    if x == 54:
                        if "-" in line[75:94]:
                            compound1 = 0
                        else:
                            compound1 = str(line[75:94].strip())
                        print(compound1)
                        datasheet.write(int(rootdir)+2,int(flask),compound1)
                    if x == 56:
                        if "-" in line[75:94]:
                            compound2 = 0
                        else:
                            compound2 = str(line[75:94].strip())
                        print(compound2)
                        datasheet.write(int(tdirs)+int(rootdir)+6,int(flask),compound2)
```

However, if I replace the `str(line[75:94].strip())` with a `float(line[75:94].strip())`, then I get a `cannot convert string to float` error. The printing was just for my own troubleshooting but isn't seeming to give me any extra information.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What is the exact string that you are trying to convert to a float in that instance?

Comment: Using the sample Report.TXT I provided, the string corresponding to "Compound1" would be " 7.00746e-1".  I used the strip() command to try and isolate only the number, since my line[75:94] command returns some blank spaces.

Comment: Ah I just realized that possibly python isn't recognizing the exponent as a proper float?  At any rate, this same problem is occuring with numbers that only have decimals and no exponent

Comment: `" 7.00746e-1"` can be converted to a `float` just fine (you don't need to `strip()` the whitespace for that, by the way). Can you put the offending line in a `try` block and then put a `print(repr(line[75:94].strip()))` in the corresponding `except` block?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think this is leading to the problem.  When I do this, I get the following print output for each line:    1 0 . 6 9 9 7 4
'\x00 \x001\x000\x00.\x006\x009\x009\x007\x004'.  I'm not sure where the x001 things are coming from.  The preceding numbers are accurate from the text file, however.

Comment: `\'x00'` is a space (try `print('\x00')`), so if it's really printing all that, then it has the number string with a bunch of spaces followed by the same number string with the spaces replaced with their Unicode representation. Go back and take a careful look at your input files.

Comment: I just noticed something.  The correctly-printed number occurred from the print(compound1) command.  When I add in the try block for writing to excel, the exception runs and unicode output (e.g. '9\x00.\x009\x005\x008\x001\x006\x00e\x00-\x002')  occurs from the command you gave me print(repr(line[75:94].strip()))

Comment: Does it `print()` with a space between every character?

Comment: Yes, the correct number is printed with a space between every character. eg "9 . 9 5 8 1 6 e - 2" and the corresponding printed unicode is '9\x00.\x009\x005\x008\x001\x006\x00e\x00-\x002'

Comment: Try adding `.replace(' ','')` before converting it to `float` (I have no idea where the extra spaces are coming from).

Comment: Interestingly, even after adding a .replace(' ','') and then printing the variable, it still contains spaces.  I had hoped I was doing something obviously wrong when I asked this question but this doesn't seem to make any sense to me at all!

Comment: `' ' in str(line[75:94].strip().replace(' ',''))` returns `True`?

Comment: The command you suggested (' ' in str(line[75:94].strip().replace(' ',''))) returns False in every case.

Comment: Your line of help has led me to this relevant question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603115/python-opens-text-file-with-a-space-between-every-character - which I think I am going to try out now.

Comment: Tigerhawk thank you for all of the help!  It turns out my problem was related to my input, as you had suspected.  I needed to add an , encoding='ascii' to my file-opening statement and that has cleared everything up.

Answer (score 0):

converting to float is not such a  good idea in this case.
since you are copying it to a delimited file, it doesnt matter if you convert to float or not. more over(the floating point issue in python suggest not to convert to float using the standard library float() method.

you will be better of writing the sting values since you would want to have you lab results accurate.

use numpy to convert the complex numbers to decimal if it is necessary.

Comment: If i output a string into Excel then it does not let me perform any numerical calculations with it.  Even highlighting the columns and converting to a number isn't letting me do any calculations with them.  I think it may be possible that my problem above is related to this issue though.

Comment: You should be able to format the cells as numbers - this should actually happen automatically. If Excel isn't recognizing those values as numbers, you should take another look at your input files.